# calling method dynamically through variables in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, webpack-2

Is it possible to call the method through variables? I have drag and drop elements having ID and according to id I have to call the method.
Consider the following Eg.

```
<template>
   <div>
    <div id="draggable">
      <div class="draggable" id="db">Step2</div>
      <div class="draggable" id="spstep"> Step</div>
      <div class="draggable" id="merge">Merge</div>
      <div class="draggable" id="copy">copy</div>
    </div>
     <div id="id="draggable"">Drop Here</div>
   </div>
 </template> 

<script>
  export default {

  data () {

   }
  mounted () {
  var _this = this
  $(".draggable").draggable({
     grid: [ 20, 20 ],
     appendTo: '#droppable',
     // containment: "window",
     cursor: 'move',
     revertDuration: 100,
     revert: 'invalid',
     helper: 'clone',
     refreshPositions: true,
     scroll: true,
     containment: "document",
      zIndex: 10000,
 });

 $("#droppable").droppable({
     accept: ".draggable",
     tolerance: "intersect",
     drop: function (event, ui) {         
       var leftPosition  = pos.left;//ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left;
       var topPosition   = pos.top;//ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;
       console.log(leftPosition + "  "+ topPosition);
       var type = ui.draggable.attr("id");

       //Here call methods according to id of draggable element
       //like 
       //current implement which is not enhanced code
       if(type == 'db')
          _this.db()

       if(type == 'spstep')
          _this.spstep()

       if(type == 'merge')
          _this.merge()

       if(type == 'copy')
          _this.copy()   
        //desired implementation alike
        _this.[type]() // this syntax is wrong and throws an error  
       }
     }); 
 }
 methods: {
  db(){
    //db called do something
  }
  spstep(){
    //spstep called do something
  }
  merge(){
    //merge called do something
  }
  copy(){
    //copy called do something
  }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Above is my sample code in which I have mentioned my requirements in comments.I want to call the methods according to dragged element. I don't know even this is possible but by this approach, I can reduce lots of unwanted code.

Any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Javascript if you are an object like this :

```
const foo = {
    bar() {},
    baz() {}
};
```

To call this "dynamicly" you should type

```
foo['bar']()
foo['baz']()
```

So, in your case, instead of :

```
this.[type]()
```

You should type :

```
this[type]()
```

> Object could be manipulated like array index but, in this case, indexes are juste the fields

**Warning** : Your `$.droppable().drop` function is not correctly binded. So, at this time, the `this` is not the VueJS component :

- in basics functions/methods of your vuejs component use the es6 functions fields (like your mounted, ...).
- Inside this functions, use arrow function to kepp the right context for `this`. In this example, your `drop` function must be an arrow function to work correctly

Comment: it throws error "TypeError: this[type] is not a function", Also I want to implement in vuejs.

Comment: What is the value of `type` when it throws that error?

Comment: @RoyJ, a string "db", "spstep" as mentioned on draggable element

Comment: And what is `this` at that point? I suspect it's not your component. You may want do `var self = this;` in your `mounted` and use `self` inside the jQuery setups.

Comment: `seft = this` is really bad. Use the arrow functions instead of :

- in basics functions/methods of your vuejs component use the es6 functions fields (like your mounted, ...).
- Inside this functions, use arrow function to kepp the right context for `this`. In this example, your `drop` function must be an arrow function to work correctly

Comment: @RoyJ, "this" is the instance of component, so to access the method we do like this.db(), or this.spstep() and so on, so basically its way to call the methods in vuejs

Comment: @RoyJ, As per your suggestion I am using "_this" for vuejs "this" so that its can be differentiated with jquery "this"

Comment: @AmitSharma You still have the `.` in `_this.[type]()`. You need to remove the `.`.

Comment: @AmitSharma I recommand you to use the arrow function or the `.bind(this)` instead of copy of this

Comment: @throrin19 How do i pass the parameter in the method ?

Comment: @milan-maharjan exactly the same with other function `this[type](param1, param2)`

Answer (score 4):

you just think i pass the function as a dynamic.

I pass the function name as a "saveRecord".

try this way. It works well for me :)

```
var mydynamic_Function_Name = "saveRecord";
this[mydynamic_Function_Name]();
```

Comment: I tried this[`get${type}FieldValue`](this.action, this.field.id) but I get an error "not a function".

Comment: Same for this <template v-if="[`get${type}FieldValue`](action, field.id) !== undefined"> in VueJS